# How do I make additional text appear when you hover over a menu item?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make text show up on hover after a menu item (so if the menu says HOME I'd want WERE THE HEART IS to show up when I hover over the home part). I found this question with a way to do it (http://bit.ly/1UgPYoK) but I can't locate the menu div in my theme's files in order to add the hidden text div after it. Can I add the div for the hidden text somewhere else or does it have to be contained in the div for the hover item? Is there an easy way to find where the menu text is located in the code? I hope this all makes sense... I researched a bunch of questions and I understand how to do it if I can just find the right div. I'm very new to this!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I can't find the menu div... See comment to @datscreamer below.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're looking for the **HTML** `title` attribute. Consider the following:

```html
<div>Hover over <span title="IS WERE THE HEART IS...">HOME</span></div>
```

Or is this not at all what you're looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

**Update**

[Disclaimer, this is a purely HTML answer - and doesn't utilize CSS.]

Answer (score 1):

This is done with CSS and HTML. What you do is take advantage of CSS display tag. You can go more advanced and style with more accuracy because you could add any other tags inside the span (i.e div,ul...) into it and make a block with colors that look the same in all browsers.

```css
.more-info { 
    display: none;
}

p:hover .more-info {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Home<span class="more-info">Is where the heart is.</span></p>
```

If this does not help you then please clarify:
You can't locate the menu div?
Please provide what code you are working with so we may explore your question in further detail.

Comment: Yeah, I can't locate the menu div. I'm using the Spacing theme and I can't find where in the code that the menu is located. There's a php file for the header that has the following code: 
`<div id="header">

<div id="wrapper"> 

<div class="container clearfix">

<div id="navigation">

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'custom_menu' ) ); ?>
               
                <?php if($of_option['st_responsive']) responsive_select_nav() ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply locate the item by Its own id through `document.getElementById(item_id)` and then set the title AND the alt property to make sure that is cross-compatible. 
`var item=document.getElementById(foo_id); item.alt='text you want to show; item.title='same here''`

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you meant... do I add the document.get ElementById(item_id) to the code somewhere?

Comment: You should add a script section to your html page. <script type='text/javascript>Your code goes here<script>'

Comment: I don't think I have an html page? All my files are php or css?